# MonacaでURLからデータを読み出す方法

Tags: javascript, monaca, html

お世話になっております。

サーバー上（http://example.com/hoge.txt）に在るテキストデータを取得し、その内容を表示させようと思っております。

1. テキストデータ（text/plain）をWebから取得する方法と、
2. その内容を表示する方法

を ご教授頂けないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「テキストファイルを展開し」「記述されている値を取り出して表示」が具体的にどういう挙動をして欲しいのか、がよくわからないためにマイナス票が付いているものと思われます。具体例を挙げて説明できますか？

Comment: holywiseさん,ご指摘ありがとうございます。

例えば、“内容” と記述されているテキストファイルが、サーバー上（http:/www.sample.co.jp/samplefile.txt）にある状態とします。
そのサーバーにアクセスし、そこに記述されている値（＝ “内容”）を表示させたい。
ということです。

Comment: また分かりにくい点があるかと思いますが、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 表示するのはChromeやFirefox等のブラウザ上ということでいいんですよね？ 要するにURLを指定して、その指定したテキストファイルの内容をそのままブラウザ上で表示させたい、という趣旨の質問だということでよいですか？ その辺りの説明を、質問本文を編集して追記してください。

Comment: 用語の使用が不正確なのは初心者なので仕方無い事ではないでしょうか。常識的に考えれば何を質問しているのかは分かります。マイナス票はともかく、クローズするのはおかしい。本人が monaca だとタイトルにもタグにも入れているのですから、「表示するのはブラウザ上」なのかと問い正すのも変な話です。

Comment: 確かにタイトルにもタグにも入ってるのに意識から抜けてました。ブラウザ云々の件は撤回します。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### サーバからのデータ取得

クライアントサイドJavaScriptでHTTP通信し、データを得るにはXMLHttpRequestを使います。
これはMonaca(Cordova)でも同じです。
XMLHttpRequestに関してはjQueryなどのライブラリに任せるかもしれませんが、大まかに流れを述べると、

```js
//XMLHttpRequestオブジェクトを生成
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

// 今回はデータの取得だけなので"GET"とURLを指定してopen
req.open("GET", url);

// onreadystatechangeにコールバック関数を代入
req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    // コールバック関数内でreadyStateをチェックし、ステータスが完了になっていれば処理をする
    if (req.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        // HTTPリクエストのステータスはreq.statusに入っている
        // GETに成功すると200のようです
        if(req.status === 200) {
            // 得られたテキストデータはreq.responseTextに入っている
```

といった感じです。

#### テキストの表示

JavaScriptでテキストをユーザに表示するには、alertなども使えますがDOMに追加するのがよいでしょう。
何らかのUIライブラリを使っていれば簡単な方法が用意されているかもしれませんが、自分で書くならばHTMLでpre要素を用意しておき、それのコンテンツとしてテキストを設定するのが簡単だと思います。

```js
// idが"text"の要素があるとして、
var text_elm = document.getElementById("text");

// このようにtextContentで設定すると面倒が無く簡単
text_elm.textContent = text_string;
```

#### セキュリティ上の制限

上の2点をまとめたものがこのスニペットですが、注意点があります。

```js
var url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css";

var button_elm = document.getElementById("load_button");
var text_elm = document.getElementById("text");

function load(){
 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.open("GET", url);
 req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
   if(req.status === 200) {
    text_elm.textContent = req.responseText;
   }
   else {
    text_elm.textContent = "読み込みに失敗:ステータス: " +
     req.status;
   }
  }

 };
 text_elm.textContent = "読み込み中...";
 req.send(null);
}

button_elm.addEventListener("click", load, false);
```

```html
<button id="load_button" type="button">CDNからnormalize.cssを読み込む</button>
<pre id="text"></pre>
```

このスニペットでは読み込むテキストとして
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css (CDNで配布されているスタイルシートです)
を使っていますが、これの代りに例えば https://www.google.co.jp/ などを読もうとすると普通のWebブラウザでは動きません。

WebブラウザのXMLHttpRequestでアクセス出来るURLは、JavaScriptが動いているHTMLと同じ出自(ドメインなどで決まる)に制限されているためです(CDNのファイルは広く配布するための物なのでこの制限を緩めています)。

質問の対象となっているMonaca、Cordovaなどでは、この制限は解除できます。
**但し、ユーザに信用出来ないURLにアクセスさせるようなアプリケーションでは、この制限無しではセキュリティ上の問題が発生します。**
そこは気を付けて下さい。

Monacaの場合、iOSとAndroid向けのビルドではデフォルトで解除されていそうですが、これは確認していません。
Chrome向けビルドの場合はデフォルトでは制限されており、manifest.jsonで制限を解除する必要があります。
設定の書き方は時々で変わるでしょうから、必要な時に "chrome apps Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest" などで検索するのがよいと思います。

Comment: mjyさん,ご指摘と回答してくださり、ありがとうございます。

参考にさせて頂きました。
ただ、ブラウザ上では動作したのですが、スマートフォン上でのデバッグでは、エラーになってしまいました。
ログには、
Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined
とあり、拙いながらも調べましたところ、プラグインに問題の可能性がありましたので、FileTransferを有効にしたのを確認し、再度試しましたが解消できませんでした。
何が原因なのか分からず、困っております。
引き続き よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 何でしょうね。XMLHttpRequest が FileTransferプラグインに依存しているとも思えないですし、分からないです。新たな質問として投稿なさるのがよいと思います。エラーメッセージと、エラーメッセージの原因となっているコード（それを削ればエラーが出ない事を確認して下さい）を添えれば、詳しい方の回答が期待できると思います。コードは短かければ、まわりも全部のせてもよいかもしれませんね。

Comment: 時間は掛かってしまいましたが、なんとか解決できました。
ご助言ありがとうございました。